# React Native can't find proper Android SDK version

Tags: android, react-native

I'm having issues getting Android to build with React Native on my M1 mac. `npx react-native doctor` shows the following:
[image: doctor output]

But when I look in Android Studio, it shows that 30 is installed.
[image: android studio image]

What can I do to target 30.0.2? I've tried updating all the sdks in Android Studio and using the `f` and `e` commands in `doctor` to fix the errors but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave it up in case any one else hits this. You need to go to SDK Manager > SDK Tools > Show package details, then install the proper version under Android SDK Build tools. [image]

Answer (score 0):

1. First check if you have SDK Platform 31 (or what is needed) for your React Native version, in my case 0.69.4)

[image: Sdk platform example image]

2. Now check in the sdk tools tab if the version is marked necessary.

[image: Sdk tools example image]

3. Now check if the command line is enabled (this is the most common error to have this result)

[image: Command line example image]

Remember to have the environment variables properly set (eg:
in the .zshrc file have the paths) For that, see [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup).

Your case is probably the third one, as it was for me. Hope this helps.